# Управление приложением через SSH, возможно?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ssh

Возможно ли, используя `NuGet - SSH.NET` управлять приложением в локальной сети?

Сможет ли приложение, принимать команды от SSH клиента? (тот же терминал `Putty`)

Например, нужно на удаленном приложении "winforms" включить `checkBox`, какие для этого необходимы действия для подключения к приложению? Не хватает представления, где будет находится логин и пароль в приложении...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял (пишите более развёрнутые вопросы), то у вас два приложения.

На одном компьютере у вас запущен командный центр, который отдаёт команды и в нём должен быть клиент SSH, при помощи которого вы будете обращаться к другим машинам.

А на другом компьютере у вас будет некоторое приложение, которым вы хотите управлять, допустим по командам от командного центра должны включаться/выключаться чекбоксы. В этом приложении должен быть сервер SSH, слушающий порт и ожидающий команды.

Так вот, [судя по описанию SSH.Net](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET) - это клиент SSH, то есть штука, которая нужна для первого вашего приложения, командного центра.

А второе приложение должно содержать серверную часть SSH, тут поиск [подсказывает](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11456377/5752652) такие вещи как [FxSsh](https://github.com/Aimeast/FxSsh).

Если вы хотите вместо первого приложения использовать putty, окей... но на стороне приложения winforms должна быть серверная часть SSH, а не клиентская. Putty - это типичный клиент, а сервер это... ну например openssh в никсах.

Comment: Да, нужна именно серверная часть SSH, чтобы внедрить ее в приложение и управлять этим приложением в локальной сети. Например, открываем клиент Putty, подключаемся к удаленному приложению, в котором встроен SSH сервер. И управляем `checkBox` на этом удаленном приложении.